# Accessing list of installed apps

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get installed applications permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937794/how-to-get-installed-applications-permissions)

Is there any way by which i can access list of installed apps on Android ? and what permission they used at the time of installation/or they have right now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<PackageInfo> list = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (final PackageInfo pack : list)
{
    Log.i("Packages", pack.packageName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        for (PackageInfo info : packageInfo) {
            String[] requestedPermissions = info.requestedPermissions;
            if (requestedPermissions != null) {
                for (String permission : requestedPermissions) {
            if ("your_manifest_permission".equals(permission)) {
                        Do Something

}
}
}
        }
```