# Record Internal Audio Service

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

Is possible to record internal audio (like Spotify, or any app), when the phone is locked, without root? I'm looking classic SDK, not only for Samsung.

Comment: In application AZ Screen Recorder I can record internal sound, when the screen is off, but only when headphones are disconnected. When headphones are connected just record sound from microphone. Weird.

Comment: Yes its possible, although Google makes it a pain in the a$$ ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616084/retrieving-the-application-name-that-has-audio-focus-change some of this might be helpful...