# How to get the permission status (ON or OFF) for any android app?

Tags: android

I want to get all the permissions for my app which are switched off by the user. In short I want the permission status for my app. How can I do that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at the  [`PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) especially  [`PackageManager#GET_PERMISSIONS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_PERMISSIONS)

```
getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)
    .requestedPermissions;
```

The above statement should return the [requested permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) in your manifest, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkSelfPermission(Context context, String permission)
method of ContextCompact.
check out here 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get all installed applications permissions like this.

- Get all installed applications
- Iterate over the applications
- Get each application permissions list
- Iterate over the each permission

---

for sample code you can visit link given below.

Referred from : [How to get installed applications permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937794/how-to-get-installed-applications-permissions])